# Is is possible to use the stand alone google earth on linux as a [google-earth-plugin] replacement?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-earth-plugin

I should use a web pager that takes advantage of the [google-earth-plugin]

The problem is that I'm on linux (ubuntu) and there isn't a [google-earth-plugin] for us.

I was wondering if there is a way to use the stand alone google earth (available on Linux) for render those maps.

JD

Answer (score 0):

No, the stand alone Earth client does not have the capability to be a plugin, and there is unfortunately no linux plugin for Earth.